Can some one simplify jwt authentication and authorisation in Django Ninja?
I have recently started using Django ninja for REST API.
I found it extremely easy but for the authentication flow.  I just can't understand what exactly I can do for the following.
Create  a registration API which registers a user with email address, password and full name (later I may add other stuff ).
Send username and password to a view with the url api/login and then get a jwt token.  Note that just one jwt token is sufficient for now, so pair is not necessary.
Now protect a few important views and only allow access if the token is valid.
I understand that @router.get, post etc will have one injection of this middleware.
But I can't get a simple tutorial or article that tells me exactly what I need to do.
Every one has some different approach, some using framework_simplejwt and some doing it with ninja-extra.  I just need a plain simple flow.  So any help would be appreciated.
I understand that I need to extent the django user class and also I understand router and api objects.
All I need is that I create token using the secret key and issue it on login and then check it on every subsequent request.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can check django-ninja-jwt. It`s pretty straightforward and you can customize it to your preferences in your django project settings.py(check django-ninja-jwt/settings)

In your description, I write some example codes with ninja_jwt, authorization with email and password.
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ninja_jwt.tokens import Token

@user_router.post('/login', auth=None)
def login(request, payload: SignInSchema): 
    user_model = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = user_model.objects.get(email=payload.email)
    except user_model.DoesNotExist:
        # User is not existed
        return 
    if user.check_password(payload.password):
        # User Password incorrectly 
        return
    token = Token.for_user(user)
    return token

